# get request throwing 404 error in Angular 5 app

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, mongoose, angular5

I am a newbie to Angular.I am creating a demo video player app, following youtube series, but I am struck at a point where I can't get data for my get request.I am using Angular 5.2.10.Below are my files and code:

- server.js:

```
    const express = require('express');
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    const path = require('path');
    const api = require('./server/routes/api');
    const port = 3000;
    const app = express();

    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'dist')));
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use('/api',api);

    app.get('*',(req,res)=>{
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'dist/index.html'));
    });

    app.listen(port,function(){
        console.log("server running on localhost"+port);
    });
```

- api.js:

```
        const express = require('express');
        const router = express.Router();
        const mongoose = require('mongoose');
        const Video = require('../models/video');
        const
    db="mongodb://usersubhash:subhashpwd@ds217350.mlab.com:17350/videoplayer";
        mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
        mongoose.connect(db,function(err){
            if(err){
                console.log("Error!"+err);
            }
        });
        router.get('/videos',function(req,res){
            //res.send('api works');
            Video.find({}).exec(function(err,videos){
                if(err){
                    console.log("error retrieving videos");
                }else{
                    res.json(videos);
                }
            });
        });
        module.exports = router;
```

- video.js:

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
    const videoSchema = new Schema({
        title:String,
        url:String,
        description:String
    });

    module.exports = mongoose.model('video',videoSchema,'videos');
```

- video.ts:

```
    export class Video {
        _id:string;
        title:string;
        url:string;
        description:string
    }
```

- environment.ts

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  apiUrl: 'http://localhost:3000'
};
```

- video.service.ts:(where I have getVideos() method)

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import {Http,Response} from '@angular/http';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
    @Injectable()
    export class VideoService {

      constructor(private _http:Http) { }
      private _getUrl = `${environment.apiUrl}/api/videos`;
      getVideos(){
        return this._http.get(this._getUrl).map((response:Response)=> response.json());
      }
    }
```

- videoCenter.component.ts:(where I am subscribing to getVideos() method):

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
        import {Video} from '../video';
        import { VideoService } from '../video.service';
        @Component({
          selector: 'app-video-center',
          templateUrl: './video-center.component.html',
          styleUrls: ['./video-center.component.css'],
          providers:[VideoService]//,Http,HttpClientModule
        })
        export class VideoCenterComponent implements OnInit {
          myAllVideos:Array;//here I want to put my get Request Data
          constructor(private _videoService:VideoService) { }

          selectedVideo:Video;

          onSelectVideo (video:any){
            this.selectedVideo=video;
          }

          ngOnInit() {
            this._videoService.getVideos().subscribe(result => this.myAllVideos = result);
          }

        }
```

When I run

```
node server.js
```

in VSCode terminal , then in POSTMAN app I can get all records by requesting GET in "localhost:3000/api/videos".But in my app, I am unable to load data which is running in 4200 port.
When I click on button which loads video-center.component.ts , getVideos() is triggered in ngOnInit() but it throws this error:
[image: error]
[image: networkTabError]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your screenshot showing the error has this url:

http://localhost:4200/api/videos

But your `server.js` says:

```
const port = 3000;
```

So your server is running on port 3000, not 4200. Port 4200 is normally where Angular runs.

So you need to modify your getUrl:

```
private _getUrl = "http://localhost:3000/api/videos";
```

Rather than hard code this I suggest you read-up on how to setup an [environment](https://medium.com/beautiful-angular/angular-2-and-environment-variables-59c57ba643be) file, and put the host part "http://localhost:3000" in the environment file and read it from there. Then your code could be:

```
private _getUrl = `${environment.apiUrl}/api/videos`;
```

**NOTE**

Just to be clear - although Angular runs on the client, it is an app that has to be started from somewhere. For example, in a production situation you might have this:

https://app.mydomain.com  <- users visit this, and the browser starts running your angular app

https://api.mydomain.com <- your angular app will get its data from here

In production it's quite likely both of these urls will be accessed on port 80. But since the subdomains are different (`api` versus `app`) that is perfectly fine.

However, when running locally in development mode, you cannot run two different things (ie. an Angular application and a Node application) on the same address (localhost) with the same port.

Since you are running them both on localhost, they must have different ports. So when you wrote:

```
return this._http.get(this._getUrl)...
```

it is defaulting to where Angular itself is running, localhost:4200, not your api. You need to tell angular your api is on port 3000.

Comment: I went through link given and updated both enivronment.ts and video.service.ts. But when I make a call I get this new error ( previous 404 error is gone).
GET http://localhost:3000/api/videos 0 () in core.js
Error:Response {_body: ProgressEvent, status: 0, ok: false, statusText: "", headers: Headers, …} in zone.js
In network tab (chrome debugger),Request Headers is showing this warning:
Provisional headers are shown
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Referer: http://localhost:4200/videos

Comment: Since the 404 is gone - you are now correctly hitting your node.js/server side code - please mark this correct and create a new question. You now have a different issue, which requires more detail than a comment will allow.